# How to convert int year into valid date format in my stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, getdate

My stored proc has the following select statement:

```
select Name,Holiday from tblNames where ID = @ID and DATENAME(YEAR, GETDATE()) = @Year
```

When executing the statement I have an error

> "Error converting data type int to nvarchar."

How can I convert `@Year` parameter to a correct year?

Comment: As it turns out the title of this question should be changed to "How to get the year part of a date as an integer value?"

Answer (score 2):

The return type of the `datename` function is `nvarchar`, you want the `datepart` function that returns an integer value, so change to `DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())` instead.

`datename` is what you would use to get the name of a month or weekday.

Or you could use the `year(getdate())` function instead as Gordon L mentioned in a comment.

Comment: Or better yet, just use `year()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Or that, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to switch back from fixing specific error message to the original question. You have a date in your table and need to filter it by range. So just provide to server the range bounds. This will also avoid any conversions of stored data. To avoid tail time issue you may append '23:59:59.997' to the upper bound of range or (my advice) provide next date and compare by `<` instead of `<=`

```
set @startdate = ...
set @enddate = dateadd(dd, 1, ...)

select *
from mytable
where t.date >= @startdate and t.date < @enddate
```

Complicated conversions can make it impossible to use appropriate index. If you can convert your arguments and provide prepared values to server - strive to do so.